# Not understanding how my variables are initialized

Tags: java, class, variables, constructor, initialization

so I think I'm missing something. I am aware that

1. If no constructor is supplied java makes one for you.
2. If there's a constructor defined, default constructor by java is not used.
3. Constructor is used to initialize variables

Here's some simple code:

```
class a {

    int f; // a variable with no value
    int c; // a variable later initialized by the constructor
    int b = 5; // this will be second question, a less important one

    a(){
        c = 1; // Constructor initiatives C, but not F
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        a var = new a();
        System.out.print(var.f); // Please see my comment below
    }


}
```

Here's what I do not understand. Why is var.f printed? I did not initialize f in the constructor, however, there's no compile error and 0 value is initialed. I don't understand  how '0' is initialized to 'f' despite me not having used it in constructor

Regarding b = 5, I understand what this code leads to, however, I do not think I understand what/who does the initialization here, is it new operator or something else? Thanks.

Edit: since the answers so far are not addressing my question

---

I am aware of the default values. I thought it was the default constructor that assigned them, is it not? If not, what assigns default values?

Comment: What do you mean with " 'null' is initialized to 'f'"? `f` should be initialized to `0`.

Comment: I apologize, I meant 0. This is a typo

Answer (score 0):

Java like most of programming languages has default values for uninitialized variables. Every numeric type of variable is initialized to **0**-related value.
Boolean is `false` as default.
Strings and all of the objects have `null` as their default value.

Check docs for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

int is a primitive data type. By definition, primitives cannot be null as they are not objects and will have a default value if not initialized. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

If you want to be able to have a variable that is not initialized, you can use the object equivalent of an int java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables that are declared but not initialised are given a default value.

**References** take a default value of **null**.

**Primitives** take a default value of **zero**

In regards to your query on your primitive int variable b, the new operator is not required, the new operator is used when instantiating a reference. When an instantiating a reference an object is created and memory is allocated on the JVM for that object.

Strings are a reference variable, but may be instantiated using the new keyword for example:

```
  String example = new String("abc");
  System.out.println(example); // prints abc.
```

Usually you would just write:

```
  String example = "abc";
```

In the latter the literal is placed in to the 'string pool'... 
You can read more about the string pool here: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-pool-example/

Answer (score 0):

> If no constructor is supplied java makes one for you.

Correct.

> If there's a constructor defined, default constructor by java is not used.

It is not *generated.*

> Constructor is used to initialize variables

Correct.

```
c = 1; // Constructor initiatives C, but not F
```

Untrue. *Your code* initializes `c`. The generated constructor initializes both.

> I did not initialize f in the constructor

No, but Java did.

Java generates the following code for a constructor:

1. A super call.
2. Default initialization code for all variables declared without initializers. The default values are `false,` zero, or `null` as appropriate to the type.
3. Calls to all anonymous initializer blocks. (2) and (3) happen in textual order and can therefore be interleaved with each other.

> Regarding b = 5, I understand what this code leads to, however, I do not think I understand what/who does the initialization here, is it new operator or something else?

See above.

> I am aware of the default values. I thought it was the default constructor that assigned them, is it not?

No.

> If not, what assigns default values?

The constructor. *Any* constructor.